# What should I experience with growing the Auntie Wilder type of Phaseolus Vulgaris?

Tags: beans

I can't seem to find a video of somemone showing off their 
Auntie Wilder bean plant, and it makes me wonder what experience other people are having with them.

Comment: What is your question? As it stands, this question is either too broad or unclear. A quick web search gives no indication that it would be different from any other pole bean?

Comment: how is it different than other types of pole beans think if you're writing your own plant profile with pictures

Comment: It seems like you are not writing *your own* plant profile, you just want to copy and paste something. Try growing more than one variety, and then write about the difference, if any!

Comment: Reminder: The comment section is not intended for answers, half-answers, or similar. So flagging a comment as “not an answer” will always be dismissed. If anyone wants to re-read the definition of comments, it can be found [here](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).